# BootsFaces tabview inside form

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I'm using BootsFaces and I would like to place tabView with different inputs in one form and later submit all inputs with one button. It's problematic because inputs inside tabs are not catched, is there any way to do this?

```
<b:form>
    <b:messages/>
    <b:tabView>
         <b:tab>
             <b:inputText/>
         <b:tab>
    </b:tabView>
    <b:commandButton/>
</b:form>
```

Comment: Which version of BootsFaces are you using?

Comment: im using latest version  1.1.3

Comment: are you linking to the backing bean?  it is not shown in you code sample.  e.g. `<b:form>
    <b:messages/>
    <b:tabView>
         <b:tab>
             <b:inputText value="#{myBean.value}"/>
         <b:tab>
    </b:tabView>
    <b:commandButton action="#{myBean.doSomething}"><f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/></b:commandButton>
</b:form>`

Comment: Yes, i am, any input in tab is not catched